# Esper @Audit Logging

Tags: java, logging, esper

How do you enable Esper @Audit logging?

http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.10.0/doc/reference/en-US/html/devlifecycle.html#devlifecycle-debugging-audit

I tried this code, but I'm getting any output from Esper.

```
@Name('ENTRY')
@Audit
@Subscriber(className='ch.algotrader.strategy.box.BoxService.entry')
@Priority(0)
select
    case
        when currentValue > box.upperBuffer then Direction.LONG
        else Direction.SHORT
    end as direction,
    currentValue
from
    MarketDataEvent
where
    state = State.CREATED
and
        (currentValue > box.upperBuffer
    or
        currentValue < box.lowerBuffer);
```

From the manual:

15.4.13. Engine Settings related to Logging

15.4.13.1. Execution Path Debug Logging

***By default, the engine does not produce debug output for the event processing execution paths even when Log4j or Logger configurations have been set to output debug level logs***. To enable debug level logging, set this option in the configuration as well as in your Log4j configuration file.

Statement-level processing information can be output via the @Audit annotation, please see Section 16.3.1, “@Audit Annotation”.

Answer (score 0):

Esper audit logging and execution path logging are two different things. Both log to the Apache Commons Logging destination i.e. to log4j unless your log provider is a different one. Therefore you want to check your log4j configuration. The Esper downloads contain some sample log4j configurations that display any logs to console.

Comment: I'm seeing this to console, but not @Audit:015-02-18 13:07:25,250 INFO  [com.espertech.esper.Outbound-SERVER-2] [TransactionPersistenceServiceImpl] executed transaction: SELL,-100,AAPL,price=128.43,USD,totalCharges=0.00,strategy=BOX,profit=36.40,profitPct=0.00